# what is the datatype of columns of a table created using SQLsave in R

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, odbc, sqldatatypes

```
sqlSave(dbConnect,dataKR[,c("a","b","c")],tablename=XYZ,safer=FALSE)


SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME= 'XYZ' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'a'
```

This Query in SQL doesn't give any datatype, as table was created using SQLsave in R.
how do I know the datatype.

Comment: What is the result of `select typ.name from sys.columns c join sys.types typ on typ.user_type_id = c.user_type_id and c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('XYZ') AND c.name = 'a'`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The better code would be.it would bring the name of column and its associate type of data

```
select typ.name,c.name from sys.columns c 
join sys.types typ on typ.user_type_id = c.user_type_id and c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('XYZ')
```

or

```
select typ.name,* from sys.columns c 
join sys.types typ on typ.user_type_id = c.user_type_id and c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('XYZ')
```